# How to initially center an image inside inline-block container when using panzoom?

Tags: panzoom

I want to set the initial position of the image as centered how can I do that? I don't want to do CSS centering as it will be applied always only at the first time I want the position to be set as centered of the container.

I need to keep the style `#scene {display: inline-block;}` or else the panning inside bounds breaks.

How can I center this image at load initially

```js
    const element = document.querySelector('#scene');
    let panZoomController = panzoom(element, {
      bounds: true,
      boundsPadding: 0.1
    });
```

```css
.image-outer-wrapper {
  border: 3px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 500px;
}

img {
  cursor: move;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#scene {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/panzoom@8.1.0/dist/panzoom.js"></script>
<div class="image-outer-wrapper">
  <div id="scene">
    <img src="https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/5-1.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `text-align:center;` to `image-outer-wrapper` ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I cant properly explain it but it seems to then always center the image and what happens is you can pan the image out of the view on the right side see https://jsfiddle.net/dota2pro/064ke9xy/13/     I will edit my question a little bit more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zoomAbs` to set the initial position. The scale need to be different from `1` (not sure why) so I made it `0.9`

```js
let element = document.querySelector('#scene');
var s = (document.querySelector('.image-outer-wrapper').offsetWidth - element.offsetWidth) ;


let panZoomController = panzoom(element, {
  bounds: true,
  boundsPadding: 0.1
}).zoomAbs(
  6*s, // initial x position
  0, // initial y position
  0.9 // initial zoom 
);
```

```css
.image-outer-wrapper {
  border: 3px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 300px;
}

img {
  cursor: move;
}

#scene {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/panzoom@8.1.0/dist/panzoom.js"></script>
<div class="image-outer-wrapper">
  <div id="scene">
    <img src="https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/5-1.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I actually don't know exactly how it works, I will dig more into it to understand the logic and give accurate values

Comment: I found the method after going thru the library there is a `moveTo ` function added answer

Answer (score 3):

Found out a move to function Thanks to @Temani Afif for help

```js
let element = document.querySelector('#scene');
var s = (document.querySelector('.image-outer-wrapper').offsetWidth /2) - (element.offsetWidth / 2);


let panZoomController = panzoom(element, {
  bounds: true,
  boundsPadding: 0.1
});

panZoomController.moveTo(s, 0);
```

```css
.image-outer-wrapper {
  border: 3px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 300px;
}

img {
  cursor: move;
}

#scene {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/panzoom@8.1.0/dist/panzoom.js"></script>
<div class="image-outer-wrapper">
  <div id="scene">
    <img src="https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/5-1.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```html
<style>
.image-outer-wrapper {
  border: 3px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 500px;
}

img {
  cursor: move;
}

#scene {
  display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

</style>
<div class="image-outer-wrapper">

    <div id="scene">
      <img src="https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/5-1.png">

    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: I want the image to be centered only the first time, this will center every time

Comment: what do you mean by only first time?

Comment: could you explain more what do you really want?

Comment: I Edited my answer hope it makes  more sense

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<style>
.image-outer-wrapper {
  border: 3px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 500px;
}

img {
  cursor: move;
  width: 100%;
}

#scene {
  position: absolute;
  width:400px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left:-200px;
  display:block;
}
</style>
  <div class="image-outer-wrapper">

    <div id="scene">
      <img src="https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/5-1.png">

    </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This will center the img inside its container :

```
#scene {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I don't get what you want mate !